# solve trigonometric equation using matlab

Tags: matlab, trigonometry

How do you solve this equation in `Matlab`?

```
      beta=0:10:90
      sin(tetha)+(3*cos(tetha)-1)*cot(beta)=0
```

Solve for `tetha`

I used the solve function but didn't get any answer.

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: No, just trying to learn..

Comment: Saying that you didn't get an answer doesn't help us help you. How did you call `solve`? The `solve` function solves an equation symbolically. Did you want a formula for `tetha` as a function of `beta`?

Comment: That could help as well..

Answer (score 2):

Check out [`fzero`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html).

```
beta = 0:10:90
for ii = 1:numel(beta)
    %% insert fzero function here
end

  Columns 1 through 7
   -0.9273    0.8777   -0.6248   -0.2930    0.8045   -0.9177    0.9141
  Columns 8 through 10
   -0.7869    0.2148    0.6605
```